# How can I run element's click event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu-left-left">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var temp = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i += 2) {
    temp += "<li> <a href='#' class='test'> + "Test" + </a> </li>";
}

$("#menu-left-left ul").html(temp);

$(".test").click(function() {   
    alert("Element test class");
});
```

I want to load `#menu-left-left` element using jQuery. When this code block works the menu seems to look like I want. But `.test` element's click event handler doesn't work. How can I run this event handler?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to delegate the events as you are selecting the element **after** adding it in. Your problem is that the body of your loop isn't valid.

```
var temp = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i += 2) {
    temp += "<li> <a href='#' class='test'> + "Test" + </a> </li>";
}
```

There is a syntax error in your string concatenation. You probably meant either:

```
 "<li> <a href='#' class='test'>" + Test + "</a> </li>" // Test is a variable
```

or

```
 "<li> <a href='#' class='test'>Test</a> </li>"
```

Here's a working version of your code:

```js
var temp = "";

for(var i=0; i<2; i+=2) {
     temp += "<li> <a href='#' class='test'> Test </a> </li>";
}

$("#menu-left-left ul").html(temp);

$(".test").click(function() {   
    alert("Element test class");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-left-left">
 <ul>

 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use delegated events as the element you're targetting is added dynamically. Try this :

```
$("#menu-left-left ul").on("click","li a.test",function() {   
alert("Element test class");
```

});

Comment: Oups, too late... +1 for Satpal :-)